# Paramiko can't send all commands using exec_command

Tags: python, paramiko, execcommand

If I run `command='ps'` or `'ls'` and similar, all is okay. But, when I want to download logs to my winscp from remote host then is a problem, there is no error but nothing happens.

```
import sys
import time
import socket
import paramiko
import os
import telnetlib
import time
import subprocess
import os

hostname = 'localhost'
port = 22
command=('log -c')
pliczek='pliczek.txt'

client = paramiko.SSHClient()

def connection(hostname, port):

    try:
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        sock = socket.socket()
        sock.connect((hostname, port))
        t = paramiko.Transport(sock)
        t.connect()
        t.auth_none('root')
        client._transport = t

    except:
        print ('Error')

def commands(command):

    plik= open(pliczek, 'w+')
    chan =  client.get_transport().open_session()

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    stdin = client.exec_command(command)
    output = stdout.readlines()
    stdin.close()


    lista=''.join(output)
    print(lista)
    plik.write(lista)

    plik.close()
    print lista

def close_sesion():
    client.close()
    print 'closed'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "download logs **to my winscp**"?

Comment: Where do you call `connection` and `commands`? Show us [mcve].

Comment: Did you try the same using a command-line SSH client first? Like `plink root@localhost "log -c"`? or `ssh root@localhost "log -c"`